# Static map in OBJECT tag DATA attribute not rendering

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

This issue does seem to be specific to google chrome:

I currently have this code in web page which renders properly in firefox & explorer but in google chrome is does not render anything.

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=13107+Atlantic+Blvd,Jacksonville,FL+32225&zoom=14&size=300x200&markers=color:blue|label:A|13107+Atlantic+Blvd,+Jacksonville,+Duval,+Florida+32225&sensor=false"></object>
```

However, when I place the URL in the data attribute directly into chrome as a URL is does render properly. W3schools.com says that the  tag and its attributes are fully supported by chrome, anybody got any idea if this is a bug or something else I need to add/do to this tag for it to perform properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, the server sends a `x-frame-options`-header with the value SAMEORIGIN, which should prevent the file from  being loaded in an external iframe(or even an object).

Use an `<img/>`  instead.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Molle - That worked fine. It seems strange that it was processed without a problem in the other browsers but not chrome. Also, I have never tried using an image src that required "processing attributes" like the Google static maps API does - so I learned something new. Thanks again.